# How to send users their password by email upon registration in classipress?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have a registration form which only contains username and email as input and I am using classipress. After clicking the register button, the username and email is stored in database. So after that, password will generate and I want that generated password to be sent to user's registered Email address.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please post your php code which is storing fields in database sending emails.

Comment: If you are using Wordpress, than specify Plugin or Widget name you are using!

Comment: Sorry  Mujahed AKAS, I forgot to mention. I used the Classipress which is a Wordpress Ads Theme.

Comment: Hi @BillyRanario if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/287197 by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use PHP `mail()` function to send email through script, You can find documentation here [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)